# C gettimeofday Doesn't Work Properly With GoLang

Tags: c, go

I've a simple `C` function which I call from `GoLang`. In my `C` function I'm using `gettimeofday` function. I understand that this function doesn't give accurate time and I'm okay with that as I only need to get some idea. I just want to get the time difference to run a big `for loop`.When I run the `C` function from a `C` program, it works fine. The `for loop` takes around 3 seconds to finish. But if I call the same function from `GoLang`, it looks like that it doesn't take any time in the `for loop` The program finishes immediately.

Here goes my code.

**timetest.h**

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include<stdio.h>


int TimeTest(){
  int i=0;
  int j = 1000000000;
    unsigned long long startMilli=0;
  unsigned long long endMilli=0;
    struct timeval te;

    gettimeofday(&te, NULL);
    startMilli = te.tv_sec*1000LL + te.tv_usec/1000;

    for (i=0; i<1000000000; i++){
        if (j-1 == i){
            printf("matched\n");
        }
    }

    gettimeofday(&te, NULL);
    endMilli = te.tv_sec*1000LL + te.tv_usec/1000;

    printf("Start = %d End = %d Total time %d\n", startMilli, endMilli, endMilli - startMilli);

    return endMilli - startMilli;
}
```

**test.go**

```
package main

// #include <sys/time.h>
// #include "timetest.h"
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main(){
  diff := C.TimeTest()

  fmt.Println(diff)
}
```

**Main.c**

```
#include"timetest.h"

int main(){
  int diff = TimeTest();

  printf("%d\n", diff);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `j`? It seems to come out of nowhere.

Comment: I was a variable initialized to loop length. Added in the code.

Comment: With optimization enabled, the C compiler will optimize your loop away, and generate code that simply does: `i = 999999999;  printf("matched\n");`